# SocketIO does not work in components of other routes in REACT

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, react-hooks, socket.io

I have a component called NAV this component is static in the application, in that component I handle the socket.on listener to store the notification information, if there is a path that does not contain the socket it works normal, but when I put the socket in a component Inside of a route in react, the socket that was inside the NAV component stops working, I swear I must repeat the socket.on code of the NAV component so that the information can arrive again, this is a bad practice because the code should not be repeated so much This happens to me with 5 components in different routes, but I don't know how to prevent this from happening

I tried to make a component that covers all the components inside the routes and manages the sockets information there but it didn't work for me.

**THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE IN THE SOCKET ON THE SERVER**

```
socket.on("received event", async (id, productID) => {
  if (id || productID) {
    let product;

    if (productID !== undefined)
      product = await Product.findById(productID);

    const user = getUser(id ? id : product.owner);

    if (user.length > 0)
      user.map((user) => io.to(user.socketId).emit("received event"));
  }
});
```

**THIS IS THE CODE THAT I HAVE IN THE NAV BUT I HAVE TO REPEAT IT IN EACH ROUTE THAT INTEGRATES THE SOCKET**

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("received event", async () => {
    await searchNotifications();
  });

  return () => socket.off();
});
```

**THIS IS THE MAIN APP COMPONENT**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <LoadingZone>
      <Nav /> // HERE IS THE "SOCKET" THE ABOVE CODE THAT IS REPEATED
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/report" element={<PrivateRoute><Report /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/messages" element={<PrivateRoute><Messages /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/notifications" element={<PrivateRoute><Notifications /></PrivateRoute>}/>
        <Route path="/help/*" element={<Help />} />
        <Route path="/post/information/*" element={<Post />} /> // THE SOCKET THAT IS IN THE NAV DOES NOT AFFECT IT
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
      <PopupWindow/>
    </LoadingZone>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It's supposed to keep taking the socket from the NAV since it doesn't depend on any route but it doesn't, I have the main socket in a separate file where I can access the different components. But this is my problem

**This is the nav component**

```
import { socket } from "../api";

function Nav() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const searchNotifications = useCallback(async () => {
    const briefNotifications = await getNotifications(cookies.get("id"));

    const currentNotification = [];
    let count = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if (briefNotifications[i] !== undefined)
        currentNotification.push(briefNotifications[i]);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < briefNotifications.length; i++) {
      if (!briefNotifications[i].view) count += 1;
    }

    dispatch(set(count));
    dispatch(changeNotifications(currentNotification));
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("received event", async () => { // This works until I go to the Post route
      await searchNotifications();
    });

    return () => socket.off();
  });

   Return <Content/>
}
```

**This is the Post component**

```
function Post() {
   ... // Code that has nothing to do with the problem

   Return <Content/>
}
```

**It's supposed to keep taking the socket from the NAV since it doesn't depend on any route but it doesn't**

Comment: Someone here knows how to prevent it but without providing the code that implements the issue it's difficult for anyone to pinpoint the problem and provide ideas on how fix it, upload the your code.

Comment: Sorry I'm going to add the code

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]? This would include the complete parent code and complete nav code.

Comment: @MZM Ready my friend!!

Comment: "This works until I go to the Post route" - So the socket in the `Nav` component works until you navigate from *any* route *specifically* to `"/post/information/*"` and render the `Post` component? These are completely unrelated components. How are the navigation actions effected? Can you share the `Content` component, and anything else between `Nav` and what I expect is a RRD `Link` component? If you comment out `<Content />` rendered by `Post` does the issue remain? Are `Nav` and `Post` ***really* both rendering a `<Content />` component?

Comment: @DrewReese The sockets work in another route when another socket is not being called in that component, for example, to the component that is in the /help route, a socket is not found there and it works but in the post you only have to put a socket.on() so that the socket that is in the Nav component stops working

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a [mcve] enough for a reader here to reproduce this socket issue? Could you try also creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create global hooks to handle repeated useEffect in many components. For example like this:

```js
export const useSocket = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("received event", async () => {
      const res = await searchNotifications();
      setData(res);
    });

    return () => socket.off();
  });

  return data;
}
```

And in any component that needs to use socket:

```js
import { useSocket } from 'yourJsFile';

const AnyComponent = props => {
   const data = useSocket();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I looked for so many things that I returned to your publication and it was the one that worked best for me

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of context provided for what exactly isn't working, but it appears the `useEffect` hook is missing a dependency array. Without it the component(s) are constantly opening/closing (subscribing/unsubscribing) the socket connection.

Since it doesn't appear there are any external dependencies try adding an empty dependency array so the effect is run once when the component mounts to connect the socket event, and unsubscribed from the event when the component unmounts.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("received event", async () => {
    await searchNotifications();
  });

  return () => socket.off();
}, []); // <-- add empty dependency array
```

Comment: If I add the array the socket stops working completely, if I remove the return() => socket.off(); works like before